# iOS Swift Charts Chart not appearing

Tags: swift, swiftcharts

I am using this library: https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart

And I have installed it with cocoa pods, and followed the instructions for the first graph however nothing is appearing. It says this “The Chart class inherits from UIView, so if your chart is not displaying it is likely a problem related to the view's size. Check your view constraints and make sure you initialize it on viewDidLoad, when UIKit can calculate the view dimensions.” for help however I do not understand what to do to fix this issue as I am new to swift.

**edit**

I have somehow accidentally fixed the issue and now the graph is display but the lines are not and in the output box I am getting “failed to set line width” and “this class is not key value coding-compliment for the key line width”

**edit**

This is the code in my swift file I have linked with the View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftChart

class historyViewController: UIViewController {

    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        _ = formatter.string(from: date)

        let chart = Chart(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 200, height: 100))
        let series = ChartSeries([0, 6.5, 2, 8, 4.1, 7, -3.1, 10, 8])
        chart.add(series)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

**note I get a white outline around the Chart View however no lines or axis or anything else!**

Thanks, matt

Comment: Did you complete this part? _The chart can be initialized from the Interface Builder. Drag a normal View into a View Controller and assign to it the Chart Custom Class from the Identity Inspector._

Comment: Yes I have completed that part and even added constraints to the edge of the screen (which I think might have something to do with it) @MwcsMac

Comment: I have set it to be of class “Chart” as it directed me in the instructions @vadian

Comment: I’ve edited my question please have another look. Thanks @MwcsMac

Comment: You will need to show some code because at this point its just a guessing game with out seeing the code related to the chart.

Comment: @MwcsMac added some code. Thanks a lot for the help